# Overflow-wrap with <br>

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable, word-break

Hi so I created a content editable div, I want to have a `<br>` everytime there is a new-line when I mean new-line when the line is overflows the width of the content-editable.
Similar to { overflow-wrap: word-break} but instead has a 
 wrapped whenever there is an overflow-wrap.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding line breaks you can use css to change the line height. Below is the css needed to change the line height of the text meaning the spaces in between where the line ends and new line starts:

```
.yourdiv {
  line-height: 2.6;
}
```

And here is an article on how you can use this feature. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Also try to provide a clearer explanation when asking question and show some code and explain what you've tried if possible..

Comment: Hi so my goal for this the reason why I need the <br> because I'm using window.selection() to measure each line which I want the overlapping word to form a new line with <br>